# Improve performance on SQL query with Nested Loop - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am using **PostgreSQL** and I have a weird problem with my SQL query. **Depending on wich date paramter I'm using**. My request doesn't do the same operation.

This is my working query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT app.id_application 
FROM stat sj
LEFT OUTER JOIN groupe gp ON gp.id_groupe = sj.id_groupe 
LEFT OUTER JOIN application app ON app.id_application = gp.id_application 
WHERE date_stat >= '2016/3/01' 
AND date_stat <= '2016/3/31' 
AND ( date_stat = date_gen-1 or (date_gen = '2016/04/01' AND date_stat = '2016/3/31')) 
AND app.id_application IS NOT NULL
```

This query takes around 2 secondes (which is OKAY for me because I have a lots of rows). When I run EXPLAIN ANALYSE for this query I have this:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=375486.95..375493.62 rows=667 width=4) (actual time=2320.541..2320.656 rows=442 loops=1)
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=254.02..375478.99 rows=3186 width=4) (actual time=6.144..2271.984 rows=263274 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: (gp.id_application = app.id_application)
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=234.01..375415.17 rows=3186 width=4) (actual time=5.926..2200.671 rows=263274 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: (sj.id_groupe = gp.id_groupe)
          ->  Seq Scan on stat sj  (cost=0.00..375109.47 rows=3186 width=8) (actual time=3.196..2068.357 rows=263274 loops=1)
                Filter: ((date_stat >= '2016-03-01'::date) AND (date_stat <= '2016-03-31'::date) AND ((date_stat = (date_gen - 1)) OR ((date_gen = '2016-04-01'::date) AND (date_stat = '2016-03-31'::date))))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 7199514
          ->  Hash  (cost=133.45..133.45 rows=8045 width=12) (actual time=2.677..2.677 rows=8019 loops=1)
                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 345kB
                ->  Seq Scan on groupe gp  (cost=0.00..133.45 rows=8045 width=12) (actual time=0.007..1.284 rows=8019 loops=1)
    ->  Hash  (cost=11.67..11.67 rows=667 width=4) (actual time=0.206..0.206 rows=692 loops=1)
          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 25kB
          ->  Seq Scan on application app  (cost=0.00..11.67 rows=667 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.101 rows=692 loops=1)
                Filter: (id_application IS NOT NULL)
    Total runtime: 2320.855 ms
```

Now, When I'm trying the same query for the current month (**we are the 6th of April, so I'm trying to get all the application_id of April**) with the same query

```
SELECT DISTINCT app.id_application 
FROM stat sj
LEFT OUTER JOIN groupe gp ON gp.id_groupe = sj.id_groupe 
LEFT OUTER JOIN application app ON app.id_application = gp.id_application 
WHERE date_stat >= '2016/04/01' 
AND date_stat <= '2016/04/30' 
AND ( date_stat = date_gen-1 or ( date_gen = '2016/05/01' AND date_job = '2016/04/30')) 
AND app.id_application IS NOT NULL
```

This query takes now 120 seconds. So I also ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE on this query and now it doesn't have the same operations:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=375363.50..375363.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=186716.468..186716.532 rows=490 loops=1)
->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..375363.49 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.945..186619.404 rows=118990 loops=1)
    Join Filter: (gp.id_application = app.id_application)
    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 82222090
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..375343.49 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.821..171458.237 rows=118990 loops=1)
          Join Filter: (sj.id_groupe = gp.id_groupe)
          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 954061820
          ->  Seq Scan on stat sj  (cost=0.00..375109.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.235..1964.423 rows=118990 loops=1)
                Filter: ((date_stat >= '2016-04-01'::date) AND (date_stat <= '2016-04-30'::date) AND ((date_stat = (date_gen - 1)) OR ((date_gen = '2016-05-01'::date) AND (date_stat = '2016-04-30'::date))))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 7343798
          ->  Seq Scan on groupe gp  (cost=0.00..133.45 rows=8045 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.736 rows=8019 loops=118990)
    ->  Seq Scan on application app  (cost=0.00..11.67 rows=667 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.073 rows=692 loops=118990)
          Filter: (id_application IS NOT NULL)
  Total runtime: 186716.635 ms
```

So I decided to search where the problem came from by reducing the number of conditions from my query until the performances is acceptable again.

So with only this parameter

```
WHERE date_stat >= '2016/04/01'
```

It takes only 1.9secondes (like the first working query)
and it's also working with 2 parameters :

```
WHERE date_stat >= '2016/04/01' 
AND app.id_application IS NOT NULL
```

BUT when I try to add one of those line I have the Nested loop in the Explain

```
AND date_stat <= '2016/04/30' 
AND ( date_stat = date_gen-1 or ( date_gen = '2016/05/01' AND date_stat = '2016/04/30'))
```

Does someone have any idea where it could come from?

Comment: Perform `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on both queries and add both outputs to your question. Also do you have any indexes on that tables?

Comment: MIght be a data distribution issue,changing the date means the optimizers has to scan a lot more rows

Comment: @Mihai Or optimizer "thiks" there are more rows. So it's better to give us `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output (and perform VACUUM ANALYZE on tables). Because as you know there's a lot of "could", "would" and "may" as far as db query optimization is concerned.

Comment: Edited with the full EXPLAIN ANALYZE as required. It's weird because I have the full data for March and I have only data for April (as we are the 6th). It should be faster and not slower

Comment: The problem is that in the second query Postgres completely underestimates the rows that are returned by that condition (estimated: 1 row, actual: 118990 rows). So this looks like stale statistics (in the first query the number of rows is also underestimated, but that doesn't cause a bad plan). Check if running `analyze stat;` changes anything. It doesn't look like as if you have an index on `stat (date_stat)`. Creating one should help as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you post your comment while I was writing my answer. Didn't see it before posting.

Comment: `AND app.id_application IS NOT NULL` will cause the `LEFT OUTER JOIN application app` to act like a plain join. -> your logic is flawed. BTW from which table does the dat column in `date_stat >= '2016/3/01' ` stem?

Comment: The fact is sometimes my `sj.id_application` is null and I don't want them on my results so maybe I should have put `AND sj.id_application IS NOT NULL` instead of `AND app.id_application IS NOT NULL`.
`date_stat` is from Table `stat`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, it looks like there's problem with optimizer estimations. He thiks that for april there will be only `1 row` so he choose `NESTED LOOP` which is very inefficient for big number of rows (`118,990` in that case).

1. Perform `VACUUM ANALYZE` for every table. This will clean up dead tuples and refresh statistics.
2. consider adding index based on `dates` like `CREATE INDEX date_stat_idx ON <table with date_stat> USING btree (date_stat);`

Rerun the query,

Comment: I did a VACUM ANALYZE (With only 1 C) and it improved the performance (From 120sec to 10sec). I will now try to play with Index to keep improve the performance, Thanks.

Comment: Note that really you just need the ANALYZE command, you don't have to VACUUM the table if you don't need to (vacuuming is good but can take a lot longer than just an analyze operation).