# PostgreSQL - How to make a condition with records between the current record date and the same date plus 5 min?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have something like this. With this part of code I detect if a vehicle stopped at least 5 minutes.
And works but, with a large amount of data, it starts to be slow.
I did a lot of tests and I'm sure that my problem is in the `not exists` block.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.messages
(
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('messages_id_seq'::regclass),
  messagedate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  vehicleid integer NOT NULL,
  driverid integer NOT NULL,
  speedeffective double precision NOT NULL,
  -- ... few nonsense properties
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.messages OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE INDEX idx_messages_1 ON public.messages
 USING btree (vehicleid, messagedate);
```

And my query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages m
WHERE
    m.speedeffective > 0
    and m.next_speedeffective = 0
    and not exists( -- my problem
        select id
        from messages
        where
            vehicleid = m.vehicleid
            and speedeffective > 5 -- I forgot this condition
            and messagedate > m.messagedate
            and messagedate <= m.messagedate + interval '5 minutes'
    )
```

I can't figure out how to build the condition in a more performant way.

**Edit DAY2:**

I added a previous table like this to use in the *second* table:

```
WITH messagesx as (
  SELECT
    vehicleid,
    messagedate
  FROM
    messages
  WHERE
    speedeffective > 5
)
```

and now works better. I think that I'm missing a little detail.

Comment: Probably I cannot answer your question, but you should post the DDL of the table along with defined indexes

Comment: Thanks @fero. Something more to add?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a 'NOT EXISTS' will slow down your query as it requires a full scan of the table for each of the outer rows. Try to incorporate the same functionality within a join (I'm trying to rewrite the query here, without knowing the table, so I might make a mistake here):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages m1
LEFT JOIN 
    messages m2
ON m1.vehicleid = m2.vehicleid AND m1.messagedate < m2.messagedate AND m1.messagedate <= m2.messagedate+interval '5 minutes'
WHERE
    speedeffective > 0
    and next_speedeffective = 0
    and m2.vehicleid IS NULL
```

Take note that the NOT EXISTS is rewritten as the non-hit of the join condition.

Comment: Tomorrow I will check it and if it doesn't work, I'll add more data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried, but it stills taking much time. @CountZukula

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36445233/5000827
and reading about `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN` (*where join is NULL*)

For PostgreSQL, `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN` are **anti-join** and works at the same way. (This is the reason why the @CountZukula answer's result is almost the same than mine)

The problem was on the kind of operation: `Nest` or `Hash`.

So, based on this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/routine-vacuuming.html

> PostgreSQL's VACUUM command has to process each table on a regular basis for several reasons:
>
> 1. To recover or reuse disk space occupied by updated or deleted rows.
> 2. To update data statistics used by the PostgreSQL query planner.
> 3. To update the visibility map, which speeds up index-only scans.
> 4. To protect against loss of very old data due to transaction ID wraparound or multixact ID wraparound.

I made a `VACUUM ANALYZE` to **messages** table and the same query works way fast.

So, with the `VACUUM` PostgreSQL can decide better.